# Подскажите в чем ошибка, как убрать линии

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/yxaeq1u2/1/

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

div, a, img {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu, a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 12px 0;
}

.menu, li, a:hover{
 color: #68F93B;
 border-top: 1px solid #68F93B;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #68F93B;
}

.menu, ul, li{
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.menu {
 font-size: 12px;
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 155px;
}

.menu, li{
 margin-right: 20px;
}


.wrapper{
 width: 1140px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.phone{
 margin-left: auto;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Triangles</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,500,900&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
   <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Страница</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Должна</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Быть</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Тут</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="phone">+38 093 758 23 54</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  
 </div>





<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Линии над и под ссылками должны быть только при наведении, но они видны постоянно.
В чем ошибка ?

Comment: `.menu, li, a:hover` Запятые лишние. Везде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.menu, li, a:hover` Вы зря ставите запятые. Это три разных селектора с одними стилями.

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

div a img {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 12px 0;
}

.menu li:hover a{
 color: #68F93B;
 border-top: 1px solid #68F93B;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #68F93B;
}

.menu ul li{
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.menu {
 font-size: 12px;
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 155px;
}

.menu li{
 margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}


.wrapper{
 width: 1140px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.phone{
 margin-left: auto;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Triangles</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,500,900&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
   <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Страница</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Должна</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Быть</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Тут</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="phone">+38 093 758 23 54</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  
 </div>





<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script> 
</body>
</html>
```